# Flex-direction for tables

Tags: html, css

Here is what I'm intending to do:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UDbQ.png)

Current HTML + CSS, for some reason the table can't contain multiple objects in a row.:

```css
.boardTitle{
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}
.boardTable{
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.boardRow{
  flex-direction: row;
}
.thread{
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="boardTitle">
    Name
  </div>
  <div class="boardTable">
    <div class="boardRow">
      <div class="thread">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="thread">
        2
      </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you never declared `display:flex`. Also for a table like layout you aiming for, you should use `display: grid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class name `.boardRow`  is the container which holds the threads, so you should give it a display property `display: flex` if you want them to be next each other.

```css
.boardTitle{
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}
.boardTable{
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.boardRow{
  display:flex;        <---- here
  flex-direction: row;
}
.thread{
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="boardTitle">
    Name
  </div>
  <div class="boardTable">
    <div class="boardRow">
      <div class="thread">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="thread">
        2
      </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```